# Synchronous or asynchronous in swift server (Perfect)

Tags: swift, asynchronous, server, swift3, perfect

I have created a Swift 3.0 server using the Perfect Framework. Everything works great as expected but i am trying to learn if there is a better way to do some things.

Coming from an iOS background I know to always call any blocking function in a different thread. Does this still hold when developing in the server?

For example, if I have a long blocking task (like making another request or performing a large database query), does it make a difference to call it synchronously:

```
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/", handler: { request, response in
    longSynchronousTask()
    response.appendBody(string: "Finished")
    response.completed()
})
```

or should I be doing this asynchronously?

```
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/", handler: { request, response in
    longAsynchronousTask(completion: {
        response.appendBody(string: "Finished")
        response.completed()
    })
})
```

Comment: generally speaking, it's better to run time intensive tasks -and most other tasks- asynchronously so you can do other things while those tasks are processing.  Unless you need a series of tasks to perform in a series (in order) I would do this asynchronously. I'm sure there are other exceptions to this rule, but I can't think of any off the top of my head. That being said, I'm by no means an expert in server side development, so I could be wrong. But more often than not, asynchronous execution is the way you want to go without knowing more about your program.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the framework. I wasn't able to find more information about perfect.org's architecture but since it claims to run on a "high-performance asynchronous networking engine", the expectation is that a thread handling a request is not supposed to block.

Most reactive frameworks (like Node.js, Vert.x) rely on one or multiple event threads that are handling requests.
If these threads block, no more requests can be handled!

Which means that longer running tasks should be run in their own threads.
There are frameworks that provide a mechanism for that (like worker-threads).

The question then becomes: What is a longer running task?
if your task does I/O in an asynchronous fashion and merely 'waits' for I/O, you can do that on the event thread.

If you do lengthy computation, you might be better off putting that into a separate thread.

Answer (score -1):

yes, you can. I use the following code test, it's OK.

```
struct DBOperationQueue {
    static let messageOperationQueue:OperationQueue = {
        let operationQueue = OperationQueue()
        operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5
        return operationQueue
    }()
}

func handler(request: HTTPRequest, response: HTTPResponse) {
    DBOperationQueue.messageOperationQueue.addOperation {

        sleep(10)

        print("sleep complete")

        response.setHeader(.contentType, value: "text/html")
        response.appendBody(string: "<html><title>Hello, world!</title><body>Hello, world!</body></html>")
        response.completed()
    }
}
```